# How to Set Order Status to "Processing"

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

We recently migrated a Magento site and, for some reason, an unknown a number of orders that were paid for are still marked as `Pending` (status) in the Magento admin panel.

I need to be able to change the status to `Processing` so that back office staff can view invoices, print packing sheets etc, but I am unable to change the order status. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

The reason that your `Pending` order cannot be switched to `Processing` is that `Pending` ***order status*** has `pending` ***order state*** associated with it. `Processing` status has `processing`state associated with it in default Magento.

*Order states* cannot be changed in the admin panel, as it disrupts the business logic of Magento. So, you should only manually change state when you really need to, as in your case.

You'll need to load a collection of orders with the order numbers you have identified.

```
$orderNumbers = ...; // comma-delimited order numbers
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('incremend_id', array('in' => $orderNumbers));
foreach ($collection as $order) {
    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
        ->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
        ->save();
}
```

Comment: Which location add this code 1.9.3 in magento?

Answer (score 2):

You can try sending an invoice for each order without sending an email to the customer.  Once the invoice is sent the order should switch to Processing.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

`$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();`

Syntax for setState

`public function setState($state, $status = false, $comment = '', $isCustomerNotified = null)
{
   return $this->_setState($state, $status, $comment, $isCustomerNotified, true);
}`

Other Order State

`STATE_NEW
STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT 
STATE_COMPLETE
STATE_CLOSED
STATE_CANCELED
STATE_HOLDED`